# Conversion operator between template derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following template classes,
I need to figure out how to implement a conversion operator between the derived template classes.

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base () { }

    template <class U>
    operator Base<U>()
    {
        return Base<U> (v);
    }

    virtual double getV() = 0;

};

class D1: public Base<D1>
{
public:

    D1(int j) 
    {
        i = j;
    }

    double getV() const { return i; }

    template <class U>
    operator Base<U>()
    {
        return Base<U>(getV());
    }

private:
    int i;
};

class D2: public Base<D2>
{
public:

    D2(int j) 
    {
        i2 = j;
    }

    double getV() const { return i2; }

    template <class U>
    operator Base<U>()
    {
        return Base<U>(getV());
    }

private:
    int i2;
};
```

How can I achieve the following?

```
D1 d1(3);
D2 d2 = d1;  //conversion from 'D1' to non-scalar type 'D2' requested
```

if the design itself sound or should I be doing something else?

Please let me know what ur thoughts

Comment: Two problems: 1) You have in class `Base` a `virtual int getV()` but in its derived classes it's a `int getV() const` (a different function). 2) You cannot return an instance of an abstract class (from the conversion operator in `Base`).

Comment: @DyP it was a typo, fixed 1, for issue 2, the compiler does not object about it

Comment: *"the compiler does not object about it"* probably because it cannot know at that point if there are specializations of `Base<U>` which are not abstract. However, if this function is instantiated for a `Base<U>` which is abstract, the compiler should complain.

Comment: You could add a converting constructor to each class derived from a `Base` specialization, e.g. `template<class U> D1(Base<U> const&)`, possibly using inherited ctors.

Comment: @DyP can you explain more about template<class U> D1(Base<U> const&)? Can you provide an example of how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, I don't see a reason why CRTP is used.

The specializations of `Base` all have a virtual member function that is not dependent on the template parameter. Your code suggests this virtual member function can be used to access all data necessary to create an instance of any class derived from a specialization of `Base`. If we follow this assumption, one could rather think of:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual double getV() const = 0;
};

class D1 : public Base
{
    int i;
public:
    D1(int);
    virtual double getV() const { return i; }
};

class D2 : public Base
{
    int i;
public:
    D2(int);
    virtual double getV() const { return i; }
};
```

This still does not allow conversions. However, it is quite simple to add them here:

```
class D1 : public Base
{
    int i;
public:
    D1(int);
    D1(Base const& p) : D1(p.getV()) {}
    virtual double getV() const { return i; }
};
```

This conversion should be allowed by `D1` and not by `Base`, because only `D1` knows what data is required for it to be constructed.

---

If CRTP is necessary for things not shown here, you could still use a common base class:

```
class Common_base
{
public:
    virtual double getV() const = 0;
};

template<class T>
class Base : public Common_base
{
};

class D1 : public Base<D1>
{
    int i;
public:
    D1(int);
    D1(Common_base const& p) : D1(p.getV()) {}
    virtual double getV() const { return i; }
};
```

If, for some reason, the CRTP is required for the conversion, you could still use a converting constructor template:

```
template<class T>
class Base
{
public:
    virtual double getV() const = 0; // whyever
};

class D1 : public Base
{
    int i;
public:
    D1(int);
    template<class U>
    D1(Base<U> const& p) : D1(p.getV()) {}
    virtual double getV() const { return i; }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. The reason I'm using CRTP different common operations I want to perform on the derived classes. as well I want to limit the use to only those classes

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do but I don't think you can do it as described.

If you really want to have a common interface, you need to declare a common base class that includes all the methods and properties that your code needs, and have both classes derive from that. You can then always cast to the base class.

This seems ideal in fact. Especially since you can always use virtual methods to customize behavior in the base class if needed.

If that doesn't work within your current task, perhaps you should talk more about why you need this.

Comment: Basically, I want to have a common class and derived classes that can interact with each other, i.e. can add, multiple, assign, ...etc operation on that. all works as needed except for the conversion operator. not sure how to go from there!

Comment: Then use a common base class and virtual methods, as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You either write a constructor for `D2` that takes a `const D1&` or you write a conversion operator in `D1` that returns a `D2`. You have to decide what it means to do this conversion and implement the conversion appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a constructor in your derived classes that takes a Base template :

```
template <class U>
D2(const Base<U> &other)
{
  i2 = other.getV();
}
```

But not sure if it will fit your needs.